# Symfony router with translated urls

Tags: annotations, twig, symfony-2.3

I trying to build an router in Symfony with annotation where also the urls are translated. I would like to have all the following urls routed to the same controller:

```
/over-ons
/nl/over-ons
/en/about-us
```

I use the following annotation router:

```
     /**
     * @Route("/{_locale}/over-ons", defaults={"_locale": "nl|en"}, requirements={"_locale": "nl"}, name="about-us")
     * @Route("/{_locale}/about-us", defaults={"_locale": "nl|en"}, requirements={"_locale": "en"}, name="about-us")
     */
```

But when I generate via path an url in Twig always the last @route is used instead of the one of the correct set _locate. Any advice would be helpful?

Would it also by wise from SEO poiunt of view to support .html behinde the urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding those 2 annotations on the same controller method, then of course only the last one is used because it overrides all the previous ones.

If you want good and solid internationalization support, I recommend using [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle).